# Issue with daisychaining MCP3008 SPI on Raspberry Pi with Python

Tags: python, spi, chain

At the moment I am trying to let two MCP3008's communicate through SPI with my raspberry pi and a Python script. A potentiometer should send a certain analog value to the MCP3008 input channel.

Here is my setup in Fritzing:

[Breadboard Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqetJ.png)

and here is the schematic overview:

[Schematic Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUvgy.png)

The SPI wiring is based upon a standard daisychain schematic as shown in:

[SPI Daisy Chain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulOyh.png)

The Python Code I am using is:

```
import spidev
import time

spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz = 1000000

def read_spi(channel):
  spidata = spi.xfer2([0,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  return ((spidata[1] & 3) << 8) + spidata[2]

try:
  while True:
    channeldata = read_spi(0)
    print (channeldata)
    time.sleep(.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
  spi.close()
```

I am getting values, but they fluctuate a lot with every value possible between 0 and 1023.

I've tried it with one MCP3008 without daisychaining of course and it worked fine, so my guess is that it has something to do with either the daisychain being incorrect, or the addressing of the MCP3008.

Can you guys help me out? Thanks alot!!

Cheers,

Devatu

Answer (score 0):

Might be a late response, but according to the data sheet this chip can't be daisy-chained at all.

I am also looking for an ADC which can be daisy-chained.